# @define variable not working in Blade Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Trying to define a variable in blade file but its not working:

```
@define $i = 1
```

but got error "Undefined variable $i" when try to use.

Full Code:

```
@foreach($assigned as $task)  
  @define $pcat = "";
  @if($task->tc_name != $pcat)
  @else
       //code
  @endif
  @define $pcat = $task->tc_name
@endforeach
```

Dont know where I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: Is `@define` a directive you have created yourself?

Comment: Why do you use laravel 4.2?

Comment: I'm working on project from last 3-4 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>

{{$i}}
```

OR you can use below code in your blade file

```
{{--*/$i=1/*--}}

{{$i}}
```

Hope this work for you !

Comment: Its working but I don't want to write core php code :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend blade like

Extend Blade like this:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Extend blade so we can define a variable
| <code>
| @define $variable = "whatever"
| </code>
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

\Blade::extend(function($value) {
    return preg_replace('/\@define(.+)/', '<?php ${1}; ?>', $value);
});
```

You can just put the above code on the bottom of app/start/global.php (or any other place if you feel that is better) after that use

```
@define $i = 1
```

Comment: Where we need to added Blade::extend function?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this;

```
@php 

$i=1;

@endphp
```

Comment: Can you explain more about how this helps?   Such a short answer may be correct, but isn't very helpful.

Comment: Note: @php directive was implemented in Laravel 5.2, so it won't work in Laravel 4.